# Is it possible for a corrupted .doc file to be viewable as a .jpg of the first page of a Word document?

Tags: ms-word, corrupt

I received a document with a ".doc" file extension. It appeared as a random smattering of symbols/characters when opened in Word as is, or in a text editor as a .rtf or .txt file.

When the file extension was changed to ".jpg" and opened in an image viewer it appeared as a low resolution screen capture of the first page of a Word document. Is it possible for a corrupted Word document to exhibit this behavior? Or is this a clear example of a renamed image file being passed off as a corrupted .doc file?

Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT: I have done some more investigation and Mac OS X Lion tells me that the file is actually a Windows bitmap image (.bmp).

Comment: Can you open the file in an advanced text editor (UltraEdit, Textpad+) and see the first few bytes?  If they are FF D8 FF then it's probably a jpg file that has been renamed to have a .doc extension.  Hell, open it in normal notepad and see if the first few characters are ÿØÿ

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that it has been renamed, Word interprets binary files as random characters and symbols. The only way I can think that a valid word document would exhibit this behavior is if a thumbnail is embedded in the Word document and the image viewer finds the headers and displays it. Either way it seems like you wont be able to use the contents.

Comment: Does anyone know if Word files contain this sort of embedded thumbnail?